# Wrapping a read macro in c

Tags: c, linux, kernel

There is a read macro as follows:

```
#define I915_READ16(reg)        i915_read16(dev_priv, (reg))
#define I915_WRITE16(reg)       i915_write16(dev_priv, (reg))
```

I want to measure the time elapsed by each of read/write commands.
I can easily do for write as follows

```
#define I915_WRITE_NOTRACE(reg, val)    \
do {                                    \
        __start_mmio();                 \
        writel(val, dev_priv->regs + (reg));\
        _end_mmio();                    \
} while(0)
```

where __start_mmio and __end_mmio are the functions that measure time.
But for read, if I do the same, this macro gives me an compile error, because the macros are used as follows:

```
val = I915_READ16(reg)
```

which will be decoded as

```
val = do {                              
        __start_mmio();                 
        readl(dev_priv->regs + (reg));
        _end_mmio();                    
} while(0)
```

Definitely a compile error.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `i915_*16()` instead?

Comment: i915_*16 is used in extremely many places. So, if I replace i915*16, it will trace all those places. I just want to do it only for those I915_*16 macros.

Comment: How about a separate inline function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this macro:

```
#define I915_READ_NOTRACE(reg) \
    (start_mmio2() + readl(dev_priv->regs + (reg)) + end_mmio2())
```

where you define `start_mmio2` and `end_mmio2` to be functions that return 0.  For example:

```
static inline int start_mmio2(void)
{
    __start_mmio();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Kudos for being sneaky :-)

Answer (score 2):

Create an inline function instead of a macro;

```
inline int I915_READ16_NOTRACE(int reg) {
    __start_mmio();  
    int result = readl(dev_priv->regs + (reg));
    _end_mmio();
    return result;
};
```

or if you must make it a macro, use the comma notation, like;

```
#define I915_READ16_NOTRACE(reg) \ 
    ((__start_mmio(),0) + readl(dev_priv->regs + (reg)) + (_end_mmio(),0))
```

Comment: There are no references in C (`int& reg`), if you think `reg` will change, you will need to use pointers and dereferencing. I'm not convinced that's the case though, so you can probably get rid of the `&` in the declaration altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Since this looks to be for the linux kernel, we can use gcc extensions like [statement expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html):

```
#define I915_READ_NOTRACE(reg) ({     \
    __start_mmio();                   \
    uint16_t val = I915_READ16(val);  \
    __end_mmio();                     \
    val;                              \
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass val as an argument to your read wrapper macro.

```
#define I915_READ16_NOTRACE(reg, val)   \
do {                                    \
        __start_mmio();                 \
        (val) = i915_read16(dev_priv, (reg)); \
        _end_mmio();                    \
} while(0)
```

Comment: Changed the name to be consistent.

Comment: Yes, if the signature needs to match, so the callers don't know what they are getting this won't work. I don't think there's any macro based solution which will work.